# Is there a benefit in checking isEmpty before looping?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, is-empty

I saw the following piece of code somewhere and wondered if there was any actual benefit of checking `isEmpty`. There isn't right?

```
List<Long> someIds = ..

if (someIds != null && !someIds.isEmpty()) {
    for (Long someId : someIds) {
        // something
    }
}
```

Comment: The intent is a bit more clearer, self documenting code, but personally I would not code this way.

Comment: As John explains in his answer, it is not correct to treat null as equivalent to an empty collection.  If other code wants to specify an empty collection, it should use an empty collection.  This makes everything cleaner and removes the need for all the null checks.

Answer (score 5):

Checking if a list is empty before iterating over it is a common beginners' antipattern. It doesn't hurt, but it's not necessary. It's a sign of inexperience.

Allowing null containers is a related antipattern. It's usually a mistake to allow containers to be null. You then have to check for null, and it is confusing what the difference between a null container and an empty container is. Is the distinction meaningful? Probably not.

Finally, if a variable isn't supposed to be null it's best practice *not* to check for and ignore null. It's better to let the code crash with a null pointer exception. Fail loud. Go out with a bang.

With all that in mind, I would usually get rid of both `if` checks and simply write:

```
List<Long> someIds = ..

for (Long someId: someIds) {
    // something
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It is not necessary，I like use CollectionUtil to judge

```
List<Long> someIds = ..

if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(someIds))){

  for (Long someId: someIds) {
    // something
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).